# How to find $x$ in the following

Tags: algebra-precalculus, taylor-expansion, exponentiation

Can I ask (I guess the simplest question) how to find $x$ in the following

\begin{equation}
\Big(\frac{n}{n-1}\Big)^{x-1} = 0
\end{equation}

If I take $\log$ both sides, I get $-\infty$ on the the R.H.S.

If I inverse the equations, I get $\infty$ on R.H.S.

Comment: It is only possible if $\frac {n}{n-1} = 0$  or $n = 0$ you could argue that if we are allowed to look at a limit, then if $|\frac {n}{n-1}| < 1$ and we can let $x$ approach infinity or $|\frac {n}{n-1}| > 1$ and let $x$ approach $-\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if we just look at the equation in a general context, we get $B^x=0$, in which case, there's no solution. You can never raise anything to any power and get 0. Exponential functions have an asymptote on the x-axis.

Comment: ... unless $B$ is already $0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael $0^0$ is a pretty iffy topic. There are arguments for $0^0=0$ and arguments for $0^0=1$ and both arguments make equally as much sense. As far as I know currently, $0^0=1$ is the widely accepted answer.

Comment: According to all opinions, you have $B^x = 0$ if $B=0$ and $x>0$.

Answer (score 2):

$a^{x}$ does not take the value $0$ for any $x$, here $a>1$.